# Power required by a carnot refrigerator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, power, carnot-cycle

**Problem Statement**

A car interior is found to be too hot, so an air conditioner is used that operates as a Carnot cycle refrigerator between outside temperature $T_h$ and a lower temperature interior $T_l$. Say the car naturally gains heat from the outside at a rate $B(T_h-T_l)$ by conduction; this heat is the one to be removed by the air conditioner. For a steady state condition, show that the power P required to maintain the car at temperature $T_l$ is given by
$$P=B\left(T_l-2T_h+\frac{T_h^2}{T_l}\right)$$

**Attempt at Solution**

We know that power is given as $P=\frac{W}{\Delta t}$, where $W$ is the work done by the system. For a Carnot cycle refrigerator the work done is given by
$$W=Q_h-Q_c$$
During isothermal compression we have that:
$$Q_c=W_{2\to3}=-\int_2^3\frac{\eta RT_c}{V}dV \to -\eta RT_cln\frac{V_3}{V_2}=\eta RT_cln\frac{V_2}{V_3}$$
During isothermal expansion we have that:
$$Q_h=-W_{4\to1}=\int_4^1\frac{\eta RT_h}{V}dV \to \eta RT_hln\frac{V_1}{V_4}$$
$$W=Q_h-Q_c=\eta RT_hln\frac{V_1}{V_4}-\eta RT_cln\frac{V_3}{V_2}$$
During the adiabatic expansion and compression of the gas we have that:
$$T_cV_2^{\gamma-1}=T_hV_1^{\gamma-1}\ \ \text{and} \ \ T_cV_3^{\gamma-1}=T_hV_4^{\gamma-1}$$
Which gives us
$$W=\eta Rln\frac{V_1}{V_4}(T_h-T_c)$$
From here we have a direct formula for the power. However, I do not know how to evaluate the heats over some time interval $\Delta t$, what method might be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the Carnot cycle is comprised of: 2 adiabats and 2 isotherms.

We know that the temperature range for an isotherm is constant (isothermal  ~ dT/dt=0) so the only terms that survive are the adiabats since they will vary with time (adiabatic ~ |dT/dt|>1)

Hope that helps!